# Batch requests in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

My program is communicating with a web service that only accepts ~10 requests per second. From time to time, my program sends 100+ concurrent requests to the web service, causing my program to crash.

How do I limit concurrent requests in Node.js to 5 per second? Im using the request library.

```
 // IF EVENT AND SENDER
    if(data.sender[0].events && data.sender[0].events.length > 0) {


        // FIND ALL EVENTS
        for(var i = 0; i < data.sender[0].events.length; i++) {

            // IF TYPE IS "ADDED"
            if(data.sender[0].events[i].type == "added") {
                switch (data.sender[0].events[i].link.rel) {
                    case "contact" :
                        batch("added", data.sender[0].events[i].link.href);
                        //_initContacts(data.sender[0].events[i].link.href);
                        break;
                } 
            // IF TYPE IS "UPDATED"
            } else if(data.sender[0].events[i].type == "updated") {

                switch (data.sender[0].events[i].link.rel){                     
                    case "contactPresence" :
                        batch("updated", data.sender[0].events[i].link.href);
                        //_getContactPresence(data.sender[0].events[i].link.href);
                        break;
                    case "contactNote" :
                        batch("updated", data.sender[0].events[i].link.href);
                        // _getContactNote(data.sender[0].events[i].link.href);
                        break;
                    case "contactLocation" :
                        batch("updated", data.sender[0].events[i].link.href);
                        // _getContactLocation(data.sender[0].events[i].link.href);
                        break;
                    case "presenceSubscription" :
                        batch("updated", data.sender[0].events[i].link.href);
                        // _extendPresenceSubscription(data.sender[0].events[i].link.href);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
```

And then the homegrown batch method:

```
var updated = [];
var added = [];

var batch = function(type, url){
    console.log("batch called");


    if (type === "added"){
        console.log("Added batched");
        added.push(url);
        if (added.length > 5) {
            setTimeout(added.forEach(function(req){
                _initContacts(req);
            }), 2000);
            added = [];
        }
    } 
    else if (type === "updated"){
        console.log("Updated batched");
        updated.push(url);
        console.log("Updated length is : ", updated.length);
        if (updated.length > 5){
            console.log("Over 5 updated events");
            updated.forEach(function(req){
                setTimeout(_getContactLocation(req), 2000);
            });
            updated = [];
        }
    }       
};
```

And an example of the actual request:

```
var _getContactLocation = function(url){
    r.get(baseUrl + url, 
    { "strictSSL" : false, "headers" : { "Authorization" : "Bearer " + accessToken }}, 
        function(err, res, body){
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
            else {
                var data = JSON.parse(body);
                self.emit("data.contact", data);
            }
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: Would you consider using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library?

Comment: We'd need some of your code posted to provide a truly helpful answer.  You might try: `setTimeout(makeARequest, 200);`

Comment: Will this not just cause all requests to be sent simultaneously 200 ms later?

Comment: Async looks interesting. Will look into it.

Comment: Thats why the pseudo code was make**A**Request :)  @GeorgeP 's updated answer below is a good start.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library, the `mapLimit` function does exactly what you want. I can't provide an example for your specific use case as you did not provide any code.

From the readme:

---

#### mapLimit(arr, limit, iterator, callback)

The same as map only no more than "limit" iterators will be simultaneously 
running at any time.

Note that the items are not processed in batches, so there is no guarantee that
 the first "limit" iterator functions will complete before any others are 
started.

**Arguments**

- arr - An array to iterate over.
- limit - The maximum number of iterators to run at any time.
- iterator(item, callback) - A function to apply to each item in the array.
  The iterator is passed a callback(err, transformed) which must be called once 
  it has completed with an error (which can be null) and a transformed item.
- callback(err, results) - A callback which is called after all the iterator
  functions have finished, or an error has occurred. Results is an array of the
  transformed items from the original array.

**Example**

`async.mapLimit(['file1','file2','file3'], 1, fs.stat, function(err, results){
    // results is now an array of stats for each file
});`

---

EDIT: Now that you provided code, I see that your use is a bit different from what I assumed. The `async` library is more useful when you know all the tasks to run up front. I don't know of a library off hand that will easily solve this for you. The above note is likely still relevant to people searching this topic so I'll leave it in.

Sorry, I don't have time to restructure your code, but this is an (un-tested) example of a function that makes an asynchronous request while self-throttling itself to 5 requests per second. I would highly recommend working off of this to come up with a more general solution that fits your code base.

```
var throttledRequest = (function () {
    var queue = [], running = 0;

    function sendPossibleRequests() {
        var url;
        while (queue.length > 0 && running < 5) {
            url = queue.shift();
            running++;
            r.get(url, { /* YOUR OPTIONS HERE*/ }, function (err, res, body) {
                running--;
                sendPossibleRequests();

                if(err)
                    console.log(err);
                else {
                    var data = JSON.parse(body);
                    self.emit("data.contact", data);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    return function (url) {
        queue.push(url);
        sendPossibleRequests();
    };
})();
```

Basically, you keep a queue of all the data to be asynchronously processed (such as urls to be requested) and then after each callback (from a request) you try to launch off as many remaining requests as possible.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would the async library actually wait for the response to be returned before firing off the next set of requests? As opposed to say, firing the requests 5 at a time and returning immediately.

Comment: It depends how you use it. The `iterator` function gets a `callback` parameter - for that behavior you would call `callback` after receiving the response.

Comment: Cool, perhaps you could give an example now that I have provided some code? :-)

Comment: @mupersan82 See my edits. Sorry its probably not quite what you wanted, but it should give you a good start to making a solution for exactly what you need.

Answer (score 6):

This is precisely what node's [`Agent`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) class is designed to address.  Have you done something silly like `require('http').globalAgent.maxSockets = Number.MAX_VALUE` or passed `agent: false` as a request option?

With Node's default behavior, your program will not send more than 5 concurrent requests at a time.  Additionally, the Agent provides optimizations that a simple queue cannot (namely HTTP keepalives).

If you try to make many requests (for example, issue 100 requests from a loop), the first 5 will begin and the Agent will queue the remaining 95.  As requests complete, it starts the next.

What you probably want to do is create an `Agent` for your web service requests, and pass it in to every call to request (rather than mixing requests in with the global agent).

```
var http=require('http'), svcAgent = http.Agent();

request({ ... , agent: svcAgent });
```

Comment: @mupersan82: The default is to use the `http.globalAgent` *instance* of the `Agent` class for all outgoing requests (from any part of your application).  By creating a new instance and passing it to request, you create a separate pool of connections that is only used by calls to the web service API (or whatever).  This way, if other parts of your app make HTTP calls, they don't impact the web service calls (and vice versa).

Comment: Appreciate your answer. I have not set max value of sockets, or agent to false. What puzzles me is why I get an error then, if my program only executes the number of requests allowed by the web service (UCWA Lync: http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/GettingStarted-Batching). Also, if node defaults to 5 concurrent requests, then why should the Agent be passed to each request call?

Comment: So each web service should have its own instance of the Agent class?

Comment: You can have as many or as few Agent instances as your application and service architecture necessitate, but generally one agent for each backend service is a good idea.  So all requests to Lync would go through one Agent, requests to Facebook would go through another, etc.

Comment: Any idea why I get this error using the Agent as you illustrated: "http.js:1210 self.on("free", function(socket, host, port, localAddress) TypeError: Object has no method "on"?

Comment: @mupersan82: Oops, it's trying to create a new `http` and then invoke that object's `Agent` function, rather than creating a new `Agent` instance.  Updated for clarity.