# Promise.all on batch network call running out of memory

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I'm trying to find an efficient way of running a series of batch network requests to an API. The API takes an array of IDs and returns a JSON Document for each of the IDs provided, if available in the database. For a small amount of IDs like 10 or 25, the operation is pretty fast. However, I have 25,000+ (and growing) IDs that need to be made with an initial call.

I first tried to chunk these requests by ~5000 IDs in an array, and then using `Promise.all` to await for all the requests to return before merging the data back together. It reduced the time to retrieve all the documents from 2 minutes to 15 seconds (luckily this is load balanced). This started off fine, but I know as the application grows, there will be a lot more documents. I tried to lower the size that I started batching to size of 1,000 but this hit the limit on the stack and heap.

Is there a more efficient way for me to tackle this in just JavaScript? Eventually, this application can easily grow the documents needed from 25K to 50K in a week, and caching layers like Redis are currently not an option.

Here is some pseudo code of what my batch request looks like:

```
const httpRequest = async arr => {
  return await axios.post(url, {
    keys: JSON.stringify(arr)
  });
}

// ids is an array of 25000+ strings
const batchRequest = async (ids) => {
  const batch = [];
  // Leave array ids from source immutable, clone it
  const cloneSource = Array.from(ids);

  let lengthOfIds = ids.length;

  while (cloneSource.length > 0) {
    // Break off the ids into separate arrays
    const sliced = cloneSource.slice(lengthOfIds - 1000, lengthOfIds);

    batch.push(sliced);
    // Reduce length, to make sure there are no duplicates
    lengthOfIds -= 1001;

    if (cloneSource.length === 1) {
      batch.push(cloneSource.splice(0, 1))
      break;
    }
  }

  const mapFetches = await Promise.all(httpRequest);
  return [
    mapFetches.reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr.data], [])
  ];
}
```

Comment: Not related to your issue, but there's no point in having an `async` function that immediately returns something `await`ed - just return the `Promise` itself. `const httpRequest = arr => axios.post(url, { keys: JSON.stringify(arr) });`

Comment: You might find helpful this [thread's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319823/batch-requests-in-node-js) accepted answer.

Comment: This `Promise.all(httpRequest)` doesn't make any sense.  `Promise.all()` accepts an array of promises.  You are passing a function reference that is never called.  That's not an array and it's not even a single promise.